# How to chain Javascript ajax requests without knowing number of requests. (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

Lets say i need to POST item1 and then wait for a responce and then POST item2 and so on, but i don't know the number of items, i only know that they need to be in order.

```
for(item in array){
  request({
    uri: 'http://some.url/',
    method: 'POST',
    data: item
  }, function(clbck){
    <request with data item2 and so on>
  })
}
```

and so on untill request(n) doesnt finish.

How to chain requests without knowing their quantity?

Comment: One option: Promises. Here is a helper method: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-reduce

Comment: But how to chain them? @Ram

Comment: This bluebird documentation page has some examples: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.reduce.html Note that reducer function should return a promise and if the requests should not be executed sequentially you can also use a `Promise.each` helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was AN AMAZING async/await functions. But i used them on callback, which i needed to primisify.

```
// init a async function
const post_message = async (id, array) => {

    // init loop of requests
    for(let iter = 0; iter<array.length; iter++){

        // lets wait for promise to resolve or reject (no need to return anything)
        await new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            request({
                uri: 'my_post_url',
                method: 'POST',
                json: {data: my_data}
            },function(error,response,body){
                if(error) {
                    reject('REJECTED')
                } else {
                    resolve('RESOLVED')
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

and voila we can chain(await) for requests to go one after another, the key here is that await looks for resolve or reject (then, catch) on promice, await doesn't care about callback or return or try/catch methods...

Comment: Another option is async.js, which gives you a lot of flow control options for asynchronous work.

Comment: @Paul thanks, i already looked at async.js and bluebird.js also, i enjoy things more native way (not requests though)

Answer (score 0):

With callbacks:

```js
const makeRequest = (item, cb) => request({
  uri: 'http://some.url/',
  method: 'POST',
  data: item
}, cb);

// 1. reverse() so that we can start building the callback chain from the end
// 2. Build up callback chain (starting with no-op function passed in as initial state
//    to reduce) by returning a function which calls makeRequest() with the current item
//    and passes the existing chain of callbacks to be called after that request finishes

const callbackChain = array.reverse().reduce((chain, item) => {
  return () => makeRequest(item, chain);
}, () => {});

callbackChain();
```

With promises (requires a promise-returning version of `request`):

```js
let promise = Promise.resolve();

// You can always attach more .then callbacks to an existing promise
for (let item of array) {
  promise = promise.then(() => request({
    uri: 'http://some.url/',
    method: 'POST',
    data: item
  }));
}
```

Or with `Array#reduce`:

```js
const promise = array.reduce((promise, item) => {
  return promise.then(() => request({
    uri: 'http://some.url/',
    method: 'POST',
    data: item
  }));
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need promises/async-await or other libraries:

```
function do(item) {
    request({
        uri: 'http://some.url/',
        method: 'POST',
        data: item
    }, () => {
        let nextElement = array.shift();
        if (nextElement) {
            do(nextElement);
        }
        else {
            // all done
        }
    });
}

do(array.shift());
```

Or if you want it a bit cleaner, [`async.eachSeries`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) would be a good solution